# How do I create KNN graph for images in Python (with user-defined distance metric)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I would like to create a k-nearest neighbors graph for the images in the MNIST digits dataset, with a user-defined distance metric - for simplicity's sake, the Frobenius norm of A - B.

[sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html#sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph) provides a nice interface, but doesn't allow for matrix-valued data -- e.g. when I try to make the graph as follows:

```
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import sklearn

# Define distance metric for matrices
metric_func = lambda X, Y: norm(X - Y, ord='fro')

data = MNIST('sample_data', train=True, transform=None, target_transform=None, download=True)        

adj_matrix = sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph(
        data.data, 
        n_neighbors=5, 
        mode='connectivity',
        metric=metric_func, 
        p=2, 
        metric_params=None, 
        include_self=False, 
        n_jobs=None
    )
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I could write my own 'kneighbors_graph()` method but it would probably involve double for loops and lots of inefficiency. Is there an efficient way to create this graph in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten the images

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph

digits = datasets.load_digits()
images = digits.data.reshape(-1, 8, 8)

distances = kneighbors_graph(images.reshape(-1, 64), 5, mode='distance', include_self=True, metric='euclidean')
distances =  distances.todense()

# Test
i = 11
print ("Actual Image: {0}, Nearest 5 Images: {1}".format(
    digits.target[i], digits.target[distances[i].nonzero()[1]]))
```

Output:
`Actual Image: 1, Nearest 5 Images: [1 1 1 1]`

Comment: Thanks - this is a good solution. However, as I commented on devdev's post I'm looking for a graph creation method that allows for an arbirtrary user-defined metric. Once I have a baseline graph creation method working, I plan on using a perceptual distance metric which requires as input full 2D images. I edited my post to make the importance of the user-defined metric more clear.

Comment: @JacobStern sadly `kneighbors_graph` does not accept matrices. One curd way is reshape it back to 2d image in your custom  metric method, but it will be terribly slow. I suggest you write your custom metric method to operate on flattened images (vectors) rather then 2d image (matrix).

Comment: That's a good idea -- if I reshape the vector in place with `np.ndarray.view()` I can't imagine it would add that much overhead. I'll benchmark it and if that solution is efficient, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, it expects a 2D (2 dimensional) array as input for X:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html

Have you provided it one? Check, what does `data.data.shape` return?

Comment: The issue is that the expected 2D array should be [num_samples x sample_dim], but my samples are all 2 dimensional, so the array is [num_samples x sample_dim1 x sample_dim2]: `torch.Size([60000, 28, 28])`.

Comment: As a short-term fix I am reshaping the data and using the 2-norm, by passing in `data.data.reshape(data.data.shape[0], -1)` and using `metric='minkowski'`. That works to get a simple metric working. But I'm looking for a more robust solution that will allow me to define other metrics (metrics more suited to images).

Comment: reshaping is quite efficient. and any pointwise distance metric that operates on a mapping from the Dth point in one vector to another will give you a similar result - which depends on the alignment of the images (ie: not great). are you trying to find some distance metric that takes into account how images are spatially laid out? if so, changing up a distance metric really isn't the way to go. you need to project or compress down your image into some fixed dimensional representation for which you can then perform similarity search in that space. is that what you're trying to do?